# Comprehension question about tkinter and sockets/threads

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I try to display a window each time a certain telegram is received.
However, this is only working the first time after the program was started:

```
import socket
import threading
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, TOP

bind_ip = 'localhost'
bind_port = 29800

print 'Listening on {0}:{1}'.format(bind_ip, bind_port)

def handle_client_connection(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    client_socket.close()

    if request == "abcde":
        root = Tk()
        label = Label(root, text="Test!")
        label.pack(side=TOP)
        root.after( 2000, root.destroy);
        root.mainloop()

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)

while True:
    client_sock, address = server.accept()
    print 'Accepted connection from {0}:{1}'.format(address[0], address[1])
    client_handler = threading.Thread(
    target=handle_client_connection, args=(client_sock,) )
    client_handler.start()
```

The first time a window shows up as intended and goes away after two seconds.
However, the second time the call of `Tk()` does never return. I guess the problem comes from (re)creating a tkinter root window in a thread, but I would like to understand why and if there is a way to get this working.

Here is a small test client, to trigger the appearance of the window:

```
import socket

host = "localhost"
port = 29800
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.sendall(b'abcde')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('Client Received', repr(data))
```

Comment: I really don't think the problem is with `tkinter`. Try adding `print "Starting window"` just before the `root = Tk()`

Comment: Calling `Tk()` multiple times in a single Python session causes all sorts of problems.  Instead, create a single root window at the start - and immediately call `.withdraw()` on it to hide it.  You can then show/hide that window as needed, rather than create/destroy it.  Or alternatively, create/destroy a separate `Toplevel()`, and leave the (hidden) root window alone.

Comment: @jasonharper After you call `root.destroy` all of the variables inside `tkinter` get reset so it is as if you never called `Tk()`. Therefore, I don't think the problem is with the multiple calls to `Tk()`.

Comment: @Gaspode I just tested your code (after changing the `print`s so it works for my Python 3.7.9 on Windows 10) and the test window shows up every time I run the second script. Also there were no errors. Also also you need to change `if request == "abcde"` to `if request == b"abcde"` (at least I had to)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I know that there are for sure more elegant solutions, but the intention was to understand, why it's not working as expected.
@TheLizzard: Thanks. I tested for historical reasons with Python 2.7. Now I tried 3.7.9 and it works. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @Gaspode So it's a Python 2.7 problem, right? If it is, there is nothing that you can do except switch to Python 3.x

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes, did that already and swiched to 3.7.9. Probably really a bug in Python 2.7.